# What's the difference between Extrude Individual and Extrude Individual Faces?

Tags: python, modeling, extrude

When i perform a Individual Face extrude with "Individual Faces", then the faces extrudes individually.

When i perform a Individual extrude with "Extrude Individual" and faces selected, then the faces extrudes individually. There seems to be no difference to the upper method.

When i perform a Individual extrude with "Extrude Individual" and edges or vertices selected, then the tool does not extrude individual. It uses the Extrude Edges or Vertices and move method then, it performs another action instead. Which can be seen in the title of the Last Operator.

So, besides that the "Extrude Individual" tool does work with Edges and Faces too, without doing what is promised though, what is the difference between "Individual Faces" and "Extrude Individual" then? What do i overlook here?

[image]

Comment: watch this video u will get ur answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MI9B7NYnpho

Comment: Not really, sorry. This just raises the question why in Blender 2.6.2 there was no Extrude Individual Faces since the dropdown box is missing completely there ;)

Answer (score 2):

The function shifts with which ever mode you are in Vertex/ Edge or Face - and yes a lot of the times it does seem like they do the same thing...

[image: Extrude individual]

You can use <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to get to the extra functions.

p .s. the last move in the GIF was <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> just for fun.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But have a look at the Last operator when you use it at verts or edges. Then it simply extrudes like with the Extrude Edges and Vertices tool then. And for extruding faces the two methods does the very same from what i can see. The Last operator is the same, which shows that they do the same job. The Extrude Individual tool simply seems to be a double menu entry to me. Its functionality already exists with "Individual Faces", "Edges Only" and "Vertices only". But there must be a reason why they made the three tools as an extra tool under another name.

Comment: You might have a point about the way the setup is designed and whether it is optimal. Regardless of the overlapping functionality they can also work like an over-ride - like selecting all the faces but only extruding the vertices. I guess the '.view3d.' is the deciding factor. Perhaps add a Phython tag and someone might clarify....

Comment: That's a good idea. Done :)